# Eclipse debug settings

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-framework, xampp

I have downloaded Eclipse PDT 3.0.x All In One and Running XAMPP on Windows 7. How to configure eclipse to enable PHP debugging(zend or xdebug) within eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide quite useful to get started:

http://bogdan-albei.blogspot.com/2010/06/php-remote-debugging-with-xdebug-and.html

Hope that helps,